# How to send an object with data and an image in retrofit to DRF service

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to send a database object with an image attached to a web service in Django Rest Framework, and when reading some publications I found that I must send through a multi-part endpoint in my API service. But I did not find the right way to do it..

I have my service endpoint that way:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("api/sincro_establecimiento/")
    Call<Establecimiento> sincroEstablecimiento(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part foto,
            @Part("json") RequestBody establecimiento
    );
```

This is the model class:

```
public class Establecimiento {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Long id;
    @SerializedName("nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @SerializedName("numero")
    private String nro;
    @SerializedName("posLatitud")
    private String posLatitud;
    @SerializedName("posLongitud")
    private String posLongitud;
    @SerializedName("foto")
    private String foto;
    @SerializedName("regimenTenencia")
    private int regimenTenenciaId;
    @SerializedName("regimenOtros")
    private String regimenOtros;

    public Establecimiento(Long id, String nombre, String nro, String posLatitud, String posLongitud, String foto, int regimenTenenciaId, String regimenOtros) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nro = nro;
        this.posLatitud = posLatitud;
        this.posLongitud = posLongitud;
        this.foto = foto;
        this.regimenTenenciaId = regimenTenenciaId;
        this.regimenOtros = regimenOtros;
    }

    public Establecimiento() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getNro() {
        return nro;
    }

    public String getPosLatitud() {
        return posLatitud;
    }

    public String getPosLongitud() {
        return posLongitud;
    }

    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public int getRegimenTenenciaId() {
        return regimenTenenciaId;
    }

    public String getRegimenOtros() {
        return regimenOtros;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setNro(String nro) {
        this.nro = nro;
    }

    public void setPosLatitud(String posLatitud) {
        this.posLatitud = posLatitud;
    }

    public void setPosLongitud(String posLongitud) {
        this.posLongitud = posLongitud;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public void setRegimenTenenciaId(int regimenTenenciaId) {
        this.regimenTenenciaId = regimenTenenciaId;
    }

    public void setRegimenOtros(String regimenOtros) {
        this.regimenOtros = regimenOtros;
    }
}
```

And this is the code in my fragment that calls the service:

```
File foto = new File(element.getFoto());

            final SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getApplication().getSharedPreferences("MDATUM_PREFS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), foto);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("foto",foto.getName(),reqFile);
            String establecimientoJson = new Gson().toJson(element);
            Log.i("JSON GENERADO",establecimientoJson);
            RequestBody establecimientoBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),establecimientoJson);
            Call<Establecimiento> establecimientoCall = webDatumApi.sincroEstablecimiento("Token "+prefs.getString("PREF_USER_TOKEN",null),body,establecimientoBody);

            establecimientoCall.enqueue(new Callback<Establecimiento>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Establecimiento> call, Response<Establecimiento> response) {
                    Log.i("SUCCESS","Operacion con exito");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Establecimiento> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("FAILURE","Operacion fallida");
                }
            });
```

Whenever i call the service, it returns me an error saying the field nombre and the field posLatitud are requireds, but it fields are passed in the json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, debugging the webservice, note that I was receiving an object that only consisted of two elements, one called "json" and another called "foto", so I made the following modification in my service endpoint:

```
@Multipart
    @POST("api/sincro_establecimiento/")
    Call<Establecimiento> sincroEstablecimiento(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part foto,
            @Part("nombre") RequestBody nombre,
            @Part("numero") RequestBody numero,
            @Part("posLatitud") RequestBody posLatitud,
            @Part("posLongitud") RequestBody posLongitud,
            @Part("regimenTenencia") RequestBody regimenTenencia,
            @Part("regimenOtros") RequestBody regimenOtros

    );
```

One @Part per field i need to send, and also the following modification in the fragment:

```
File foto = new File(element.getFoto());

            final SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getApplication().getSharedPreferences("MDATUM_PREFS", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), foto);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("foto",foto.getName(),reqFile);
            RequestBody nombre = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),element.getNombre());
            RequestBody numero = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),element.getNro());
            RequestBody posLatitud = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),element.getPosLatitud());
            RequestBody posLongitud = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),element.getPosLongitud());
            RequestBody regimenTenencia = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),Integer.toBinaryString(element.getRegimenTenenciaId()));
            RequestBody regimenOtros = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),element.getRegimenOtros());
            Call<Establecimiento> establecimientoCall = webDatumApi.sincroEstablecimiento("Token "+prefs.getString("PREF_USER_TOKEN",null),body,nombre,numero,posLatitud,posLongitud,regimenTenencia,regimenOtros);

            establecimientoCall.enqueue(new Callback<Establecimiento>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Establecimiento> call, Response<Establecimiento> response) {
                    Log.i("SUCCESS","Operacion con exito");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Establecimiento> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("FAILURE","Operacion fallida");
                }
            });
```